# Role based access with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

So as I understand it: if I write anything in React, then the user will be able to modify it, since all the JS is shipped to be run client side. So any "security" logic should ideally run server-side.

But I'm working on a React App with Firebase auth and role based access. So if a person has an "admin" role, then my logic in React is checking if their UID is associated with "admin" in a read only collection in Firestore, and will not redirect them to the "common user" page if they do, as well as Firestore security rules then allowing the data to be sent to them.

But if the JS sits on the client side, then I assume that Firestore will need to rerun that security check with every request to and from the client, which will lead to A LOT of reads.

So is there an obvious way around this, or can I put logic in React that the user can't NOT run, in which I can basically enforce security, meaning that I can just add the security rules in my React file?

I'm just not sure how React deals with this and how much of my app gets shipped client side, and I'd like to minimize either the Firestore reads, and/or not have to use something like Cloud Functions or SSR since it costs more...

Comment: "Firestore will need to rerun that security check with every request" And that's what auth/bearer tokens are for. Read the Firebase documentation on how to handle client authentication and then follow their instructions and advice, if you're letting your React UI talk directly to Firebase. When you create web apps, your security model is the web security model, in which "people can view your code" is a given.

Comment: Look into [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

Comment: @NicholasTower This is sort of what I'm after. But I have a lot of documents (like PDF's) that are stored, and some users have admin privileges on some of them. So in that type of case I can't use the "custom claims" since I'd have to give a claim for each document on the server, which is blocked by the 1000 bytes limit of Firebase...